# Making Global Authorization Header in HttpClient Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient, angular-http-auth

I am making a global authorization header in my app. I've used the interceptor so i won't declare the authorization header in my get() functions. Am i correctly implementing the interceptor since when i call the get() functions, it still asking for the token. It says token is not provided. Is there a problem in my auth.interceptor? Should i declare the authorization header bearer token in every get() functions? I thought the interceptor is called every time there's a request sent/receive?

> auth.interceptor.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private authService: AuthService;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Get the auth header from the service.
        this.authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
        const token = this.authService.getToken();
            if (token) {
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
            }

            if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
            }

            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
            return next.handle(req);
        }
}
```

> products.component.ts

```
getAll() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).map(response => response.json());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right way!

Interceptors are for intercepting all the http calls and you can change request which is global.

I think the problem in these conditions. you can debug them and resolve them.

```
            if (token) {
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
            }

            if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
            }
```

Maybe some they are returning null!

But if the timing is the issue to get the token, you can make async call to get the token.

```
this.authService.LoginUser().subscribe(( token) => { 
   if (token) { 
     req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) }); 
   } 

   if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) { 
     req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') }); 
   } 

   req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') }); 
   return next.handle(req); 
} 
});
```

Comment: try to debug that. may be content-type is not there in heard

Comment: But why i can login to my app? How can i debug it>

Comment: put some break point and see is the execution is coming to here and everything is ok. one more thing. i am sure you added this interceptor into your module, right?

Comment: yes. in the core module. not in the app module. the core module is exported to the app module

Comment: may be you need to add it in the app module as its the bootstrap module. so put a break point and see during execution calls are coming to here

Comment: I've changed the const token = this.authService.getToken(); To const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');.  It is working now. Will that be ok?

Comment: yes, if its available in local storage then it okey. make sure its always available in client browser local storage and its not a sucurity issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155218/discussion-between-aniruddha-das-and-joseph).